# find_by_foo failing to return some records (but not others) in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my Rails app I have a model called Cycle with a "start" attribute that is a date. I'm running into a very strange problem where sometimes `Cycle.find_by_start` will return the expected record, but at other times it will return `nil`.

For example `Cycle.find_by_start("2011-05-01")` returns the following:

```
=> #<Cycle id: 45, created_at: "2011-05-15 22:38:35", 
updated_at: "2011-05-15 22:38:35", user_id: 20,
start: "2011-05-01", ending: nil, startguess: false, endingguess: nil>
```

But running `Cycle.find_by_start("2011-05-13")` returns `nil`, even though there is a record with a matching `start` value. I've verified that the record exists and the start value matches by running the following at the Rails console.

```
irb(main):012:0> Cycle.find(47)
=> #<Cycle id: 47, created_at: "2011-05-23 01:28:59",
updated_at: "2011-06-21 00:38:34", user_id: 12,
start: "2011-05-13", ending: "2011-05-31", startguess: false, endingguess: false>

irb(main):011:0> Cycle.find(47).start == "2011-05-13".to_date
=> true
```

Possibly relevant info: Running Rails 3.0.7 in development mode with an SQLite database.

Any ideas or troubleshooting tips?

**Edit 1**

Log of the SQL queries used:

```
[94m19:10:11 active_record [37mCycle Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "cycles".* FROM "cycles" WHERE "cycles"."start" = '2011-05-01' LIMIT 1
[94m19:10:19 active_record [37mCycle Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "cycles".* FROM "cycles" WHERE "cycles"."start" = '2011-05-13' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: what's the type of the start field?

Comment: Are you looking for the reason why find_by_start is not working always or a different way to do this that works consistently?

Comment: Is `start` a Date field or String in the database?

Comment: Look at the log, see what query is being run. See what you have to change in that query to get the matches you want (by running the query directly against SQLlite).  Usually, doing that alone will help you find your answer).

Comment: @apneadiving and @Dogbert: It is a date field. I double-checked the schema to be sure.

@natedavisolds: I prefer the former, but will take the latter. :-)

@Tim Harper: Thanks for the idea. Will try that next.

Comment: Have you tried Cycle.find_by_start( "2011-05-13".to_date ) ?

Comment: @christianblais I tried your suggestion, but that also returns `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Dates.... you may have a parsing problem, with US/UK formats getting swapped around and confusing things. I often find it helps to make the date unambiguous (assuming English months):

```
Cycle.find_by_start("13 May 2011")
```

Comment: Good thought. Unfortunately that returns `nil` as well.

Answer (score 0):

If :start is a date field, then it's best to pass find_by_start an actual Date object rather than a string. So:

```
Cycle.find_by_start(Date.parse("2011-05-13"))
```

(I'm using Date.parse to create the date object here, but you could also use Date.new or Date.today or some other method)

Passing a string to the finder method might work but, as you've discovered, might also not - depending on the database type and how the database interprets the string.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I've already tried using a date object like so: `Cycle.find_by_start( "2011-05-13".to_date )`, but that also returned `nil`.